# Strtotime not returing empty string on valid input

Tags: php

`strtotime` seems to be outputting empty string instead of returning the timestamp for mm/dd/yy. I am having a hard time understanding what this wouldn't work?

The output for the following PHP is:

`echo "'" . $month . "/" . $day . "/" . $year . "'";` // '7/22/86'

Isn't `strtotime('7/22/86')` a valid input for the function?

PHP

```
$month = 7;
$day = 22;
$year = 86;
$unix_time_stamp = strtotime("'" . $month . "/" . $day . "/" . $year . "'");  
echo $unix_time_stamp;
```

I appreciate any advice in this regard.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Not wrapped in single quotes it isn't: you use quotes for string literals. `$unix_time_stamp = strtotime($month . "/" . $day . "/" . $year);` But if you have that split of month, day, year already, use [mktime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) `$unix_time_stamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);`

Comment: And it doesn't return an empty string, it returns a Boolean false on error.... echo will not display anything for a Boolean false... var_dump() is useful for checking exactly what is being returned